# SQL query using NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, student and school.

**student**

```
stid | stname | schid |  status
```

**school**

```
schid | schname
```

Status can be many things for temporary students, but `NULL` for permanent students.

How do I list names of schools which has no temporary students?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Conditional Aggregate` you can count the number of `permanent student` in each `school`.

If total count of a school is same as the conditional count of a school then the school does not have any `temporary students`.

Using `JOIN`

```
SELECT sc.schid, 
       sc.schname 
FROM   student s 
       JOIN school sc 
         ON s.schid = sc.schid 
GROUP  BY sc.schid, 
          sc.schname 
HAVING( CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 1 END ) = Count(*)
```

Another way using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT sc.schid, 
       sc.schname 
FROM   school sc 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   student s 
               WHERE  s.schid = sc.schid 
               HAVING( CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 1 END ) = Count(*))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` to only select schools that do not have temporary students:

```
select * from school s
where not exists (
    select 1 from student s2
    where s2.schid = s.schid
    and s2.status is not null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.schName
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Schools c ON s.schid = c.schid
WHERE s.status IS NULL
```

Comment: This will pull school with both temporary and permanent students which should not be in result

Comment: This will only include schools where students have status of NULL and the distinct will only select distinct schools where students are permanent. This query works.

Comment: This query returns schools that have at least one permanent student. It doesn't say that none are temporary.